# how to update a column for all rows in a table with different values for each row in a table of 100 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

my table contains 100 records and i need to update a column with new values(diff value for each record) for each of the 100 records  .How can i do this. the column to update the values is not primary key.

Comment: Could you give us the column names and how new values will be assigned to each row. need more detail.

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET columnname = CASE id
                        WHEN 1 THEN 42
                        WHEN 2 THEN 666
                    END
```

With this query `columnname` will be updated to `42` for the row with `id = 1`, and `666` for `id = 2`

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with an autoicrement id and the columns of the original table.

Then

```
INSERT INTO new_table (column1, column2,.....) -- refer all columns except autoincrement id
SELECT * FROM old_table
```

Update the old table by joining with the new, assuming the is a key composite or not that distincts each row

Answer (score 0):

[Set Unique constraint on this column.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_ColumnID UNIQUE (ColumnName)
```

Now, whenever you try to update it with duplicate values, sql server will not allow:)

Also a long run scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server **2005 or newer** (you didn't exactly specify.....), you could easily use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for this - basically, you select your PK value, and a counter counting up from 1, and you set each row's `ColumnName` column to the value of the counter:

```
;WITH UpdateData AS 
(
   SELECT 
      PKValue,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY .......) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ColumnName = u.RowNum
FROM UpdateData u
WHERE dbo.YourTable.PKValue = u.PKValue
```

With this, you're generating a sequence from 1 through 100 in the `RowNum` field of the CTE, and you're setting this unique value to your underlying table.

Comment: I believe you can write it as `update u set columName = u.rownum from UpdateData u ...`. In other words you can perform an update directly on a CTE (as well as a view) as long as it's simple enough.

Comment: @John Gibb: I believe this only works if you also select the column you're planning to update, in the CTE. If you do that - you're right, you can update the CTE directly - in such a simple example, it doesn't really make a big difference, though, in my opinion. ... anyway - yes, it works, too!

Answer (score 0):

load a DataTable say dt with specific row ID of the table which you wanna update.
then execute

```
foreach(DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
{
    update table_name set column_name=desired_value where specific_column=rw
}
```